# magento 2 how to dispaly total products weight in shipping method chekcout page

Tags: shipping-methods, magento-2.1.7, checkout-page, product-weight

[image]

I want to display total products weight

(products weight* items quantity) in chekcout page shipping method lable beside.

Answer (score 2):

You have in your module, in **Model/Carrier** the `collectRates` method with the parameter `\Magento\Shipping\Model\Rate\Result $request` and you can use this `(int)$request->getPackageWeight()`.

**I updated my answer**

Below you have the module:
You can see the screenshot [image: here].

You need to create the module in `app/code/VendorName/Shipping`:

`app/code/VendorName/Shipping/registration.php` file:

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'VendorName_Shipping',
    __DIR__
);
```

---

If you want to to have the `app/code/VendorName/Shipping/composer.json` file:

```
{
    "name": "vendorname/module-shipping",
    "description": "",
    "type": "magento2-module",
    "license": "proprietary",
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "require": {},
    "autoload": {
        "files": [
            "registration.php"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "VendorName\\Shipping\\": ""
        }
    }
}
```

---

`app/code/VendorName/Shipping/etc/module.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="VendorName_Shipping" setup_version="1.0.0"/>
```

`app/code/VendorName/Shipping/etc/config.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Store:etc/config.xsd">
    <default>
        <carriers>
            <shippingname>
                <model>VendorName\Shipping\Model\Carrier\ShippingName</model>
                <active>1</active>
                <title>ShippingName</title>
                <name>ShippingName</name>
                <price>0.00</price>
                <specificerrmsg>This shipping method is not available. To use this shipping method, please contact us.</specificerrmsg>
                <sallowspecific>0</sallowspecific>
            </shippingname>
        </carriers>
    </default>
```

`app/code/VendorName/Shipping/etc/adminhtml/system.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Config:etc/system_file.xsd">
    <system>
        <section id="carriers" showInDefault="1" showInStore="1" showInWebsite="1" sortOrder="1000" translate="label">
            <group id="shippingname" showInDefault="1" showInStore="1" showInWebsite="1" sortOrder="10" translate="label">
                <label>ShippingName</label>
                <field id="active" showInDefault="1" showInStore="1" showInWebsite="1" sortOrder="10" translate="label" type="select">
                    <label>Enabled</label>
                    <source_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Yesno</source_model>
                </field>
                <field id="name" showInDefault="1" showInStore="1" showInWebsite="1" sortOrder="20" translate="label" type="text">
                    <label>Method Name</label>
                </field>
                <field id="price" showInDefault="1" showInStore="1" showInWebsite="1" sortOrder="30" translate="label" type="text">
                    <label>Price</label>
                    <validate>validate-number validate-zero-or-greater</validate>
                </field>
                <field id="sort_order" showInDefault="1" showInStore="1" showInWebsite="1" sortOrder="40" translate="label" type="text">
                    <label>Sort Order</label>
                </field>
                <field id="title" showInDefault="1" showInStore="1" showInWebsite="1" sortOrder="50" translate="label" type="text">
                    <label>Title</label>
                </field>
                <field id="sallowspecific" showInDefault="1" showInStore="1" showInWebsite="1" sortOrder="60" translate="label" type="select">
                    <label>Ship to Applicable Countries</label>
                    <frontend_class>shipping-applicable-country</frontend_class>
                    <source_model>Magento\Shipping\Model\Config\Source\Allspecificcountries</source_model>
                </field>
                <field id="specificcountry" showInDefault="1" showInStore="1" showInWebsite="1" sortOrder="70" translate="label" type="multiselect">
                    <label>Ship to Specific Countries</label>
                    <can_be_empty>1</can_be_empty>
                    <source_model>Magento\Directory\Model\Config\Source\Country</source_model>
                </field>
                <field id="specificerrmsg" showInDefault="1" showInStore="1" showInWebsite="1" sortOrder="80" translate="label" type="textarea">
                    <label>Displayed Error Message</label>
                </field>
            </group>
        </section>
    </system>
</config>
```

Comment: What you have in Model ?

Comment: I will create an example for you

Comment: Please see my updated question, i have update exact position where i need to display

Comment: Your screenshot is not the default design by Magento 2.1.7, it's very hard for me, but I can put the weight below of shipping method name.

Comment: Hi St3phan, its fine if its there alos  you can provide me code please  .

Comment: @ChalaChalapathi - I updated my answer

Comment: Everything is well?

Comment: NO , My checkout page it's self not loading ,i did as you have shared the procedure only

Comment: Can you check my module into Magento2 clean? I don't know how is your project and what many changes you have.

Comment: ok letme check and update to you in asap

Comment: no same , checkout page it's self not loading ,i did as you have shared the procedure only in magneto 2.1.7 default theme –

Comment: please run the command: `bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f -a frontend`

Comment: i have run all those coomands di:complie and upgrade and stati-content deploy and removing var/generation ,cache,pagecache bro

Answer (score 0):

First override the shipping method box on checkout page

Then you can get total weight of products of cart by `\Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart` class

**With objectManager**

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$cart = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart');
$items = $cart->getQuote()->getAllItems();

$weight = 0;
foreach($items as $item) {
    $weight += ($item->getWeight() * $item->getQty()) ;        
}

echo $weight;
```

**With Factory Method**

```
protected $_cart;

public function __construct(
    ...
    \Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart $cartModel,
    ...
) {
    ...
    $this->_cart = $cartModel;
    ...
}

public function getTotalWeight()
{
    $items = $this->_cart->getQuote()->getAllItems();

    $weight = 0;
    foreach($items as $item) {
        $weight += ($item->getWeight() * $item->getQty()) ;        
    }

    return $weight;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for comment, Please see my question, i have update exact position where i need to display